# Carry over client side customized Principal object to the WCF service side

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, wcf

I am using WCF service on VS2010.

On my client side, Thread.CurrentPrincipal is populated with Customized Principal object which implements IPrincipal.

But when the WCF service method gets invoked, the Thread.CurrentPrinicpal on the service side is 
WindowsPrincipal which is the default.

How can I make the service side Thread.CurrentPrincipal same as the client side (Customized Principal object)?

Please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way, I don't know if there's a more easy way though:

You need an IEndpointBehaviour implementation that in the ApplyClientBehavior method attaches a custom message inspector which in turn adds a custom message header (in the BeforeSendRequest method) containing your custom principal instance.  You might need to decorate your custom principal object with Data Contract attribute in order for it to serialize.  Then, implement a custom authorization policy (similar to http://burcakcakiroglu.com/?p=2189) which will run at the server end and in the Evaluate method read the custom message header back out again and copy the principal in the header into evaluationContext.Properties["Principal"].

Comment: By the way: if you don't trust the client, be careful about making any decision on the server end based upon data in the message header from the client - it could be tampered with.

Comment: Hi Toby, is there a code example that I could use as a prototype? I am kind of new to WCF. thanks.

Comment: Here's a link to somebody who has done something similar:
http://www.daczkowski.net/2010/11/25/bundled-asynchronous-processing-security-context-passing/   He's done the client bit using an operation context which is fine if you don't mind seeing that plumbing code by your client side service call.  Personally I prefer the method above where you use an endpoint behaviour to attach a message inspector, which adds a custom message object.  Unfortunatley I can't paste our company's security authorisation code into stack overflow... it makes some people nervous ;-)

Comment: Toby.. thanks for the help. In a heavy traffic website.. would it cause performance issue by passing in custom principal via custom message inspector? I was thinking about simply passing in userid via custom message inspector and then on the serivce side making db call to get permissions for that user.

Comment: the wcf stuff shouldn't cause a performance issue..obviously there's a little bit extra serialization/deserialization happening.  We use a similar approach in a high volume system without issue.  Your db solution sounds good so long as you trust the client system to pass a valid userid (and not spoof another user's) and also that your db performs well enough to tolerate the load of the queries.

Comment: Thanks Toby.. In the AfterReceiveRequest of the message inspector, I do not know where to store userid value? Is there a bag property for Thread.CurrentThread where I could store custom values and they are available through out the application? thanks for helping me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16427/discussion-between-dotnet-practitioner-and-toby-couchman)

Comment: Toby.. do you know where I could reference IdentityFlowHeader?

Comment: It's custom, it just has a single property containing my principal object.  Attrib the class with [DataContract] and the property with [DataMember]

Comment: Hi Toby.. I still have not been able to figure this out. Please let me know if you could help me. I Have posted another question as follows: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12469116/ability-to-carry-principal-object-from-client-to-service-side-in-wcf

Comment: Toby, I finally got this to work. Thanks alot for all your help.